# Avoid echoing with LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

In this twitter thread https://twitter.com/jlowin/status/1061085224862433280, Jeremiah says that the author makes the error of echoing in this article https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/using-a-keras-long-shortterm-memory-lstm-model-to-predict-stock-prices-a08c9f69aa74

"3/6 The echo is the result of a model collapsing in a fit of maximum worthlessness. The model is saying, "My best guess is that tomorrow is pretty much going to be like today," or x_t+1 ≈ x_t. You don't need an AI for that. You barely need a calculator."

Whats wrong with the author model? how should he have done to avoid echo?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming